# asp.net core CORS not working as I would expect

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've got a node app that is hosted at localhost:9000 running (React with Express). I'm making an axios REST POST to my ASP.NET Core 2.0 web project  with as follows:

```
http://localhost:50494/rest/sessions
```

GET works but POST does not.  In My Startup.cs files I believe I've set all origins and methods to be allowed on my asp.net core end points but still I'm getting what I think is a CORS not setup error.

```
http://localhost:50494/rest/sessions/6184: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is my setup on the asp.net side:

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {


        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCors(builder =>
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod());

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Can you also show your `ConfigureServices` method?

Comment: I'm showing my ConfigureServices now. That got me to think maybe addCors should come after addMvc so I reversed them but it did not help. Still same error :( @alexy

Comment: not sure why mine does not work but when I use Rick Strahl's, it works and I get my correct headers.  https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/26/ASPNET-Core-and-CORS-Gotchas

Comment: I think this is because you didn't add `AllowAnyHeader()`. Also I've noticed one more issue in your code and while you have not asked for this I think it makes sense to comment on it :) Move all if-condition with `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` and `UseExceptionHandler` middlewares in the beginning of your `Configure` method. Otherwise you will not see an exception page with details of thrown exception in dev environment and users will not get redirected to the error page if an error occurs in your MVC middleware.